# Assign one value to multiple objects in one statement

Tags: ruby

If I want to declare three new arrays (`a1`, `a2`, `a3`), I can do this:

```
a1=[]
a2=[]
a3=[]
```

But now I want to do it all on one line, like

```
a1, a2, a3 = []
```

but this fails. How can I assign them all to an empty array on one line?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To do something similar to your second example, you would still need to create three arrays:

```
a1, a2, a3 = [], [], []
```

Comment: If the object being assigned happened to be immutable (like, say, `42`), then this could be “simplified” to `a1, a2, a3 = [42] * 3`.

Comment: Seems to me that would be even simpler as: `a1 = a2 = a3 = 42`

Comment: This is a damn shame. And leaves room for bugs. a = b = [] will assign the empty array to b but a will just be a reference to b, which is not what you want. a, b = [] will assign nil to both a and b, because the array is empty and this does parralel assignment. So as you can see, there is really no other way other than a, b = [], [], which is a damn shame. DONATO

Answer (score 5):

If you insist on not repeating the `[]` literal, then one way is:

```
a1, a2, a3 = Array.new(3){[]}
```

Another way is:

```
a1 = (a2 = (a3 = []).dup).dup
```

Comment: I think this may take an extra performance hit, compared to a, b = [], [], because of the block invocation. But that is just my guess.

Answer (score 4):

[As Andrew Marshall pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410340/assigning-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-one-line#comment20054736_14410355), there is yet another, even shorter way of *assigning one value to multiple objects*.

```
a1, a2, a3 = [42] * 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby Multiple assignment is unexpected in below situations:

```
a1, a2, a3 = []
```

Above code will not assign blank array in any array variable.

use,

```
a1, a2, a3 = [], [], []
```

You need to provide number of values as number of variable are used to initialize.

Answer (score 3):

These answers are over-engineered, focused on the misleading use of `Array` in the OP's sample.

```
a1 = a2 = a3 = []
# => []
```

Test the results

```
a1
# => []
a2
# => []
a3
# => []
a4 # for sake of comparison
NameError: undefined local variable or method `a4' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

```
a1=[]; a2=[]; a3=[]
```

Comment: this way thousand line of code can be written in one liner... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Will the following snippet behave in the same way on all ruby VMs?

```
a,b = b,nil
```

The point of this one liner is to set 'a' to a value from 'b' and reset 'b'.